# Determine fish killed and the time needed to recover the population

Tags: functions

The fish, in thousands, in a lake at any time, x, in years, is modeled by the function:

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&2^x &&: 0 \le x \le 6\\
&4x+8 &&: x > 6
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
$x=6$ due to a chemical spill.

a) How many fish were killed by the chemical spill?

b) At what time did the population recover to the level it was before the chemical spill?

My attempt:

a) Since $x \le 6$, $f(x)=2^x$. Sub in $x=6$ and I get 64 000 (since x is in thousands) but my text says it should be 32 000.

b) Usually, I would put my attempt, however feeble and pathetic, here, but I honestly haven't a clue as to how I even would even start this. My textbook says eight years but I don't know how they arrive at that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) asks how many fish were killed due to the spill. So we need to find $f(6) = 64000$ (the fish that were alive before the spill) and find the fish left after the spill (which is $4(6)+8 = 32000$). Therefore, $64000-32000=32000$ fish died from the spill.

Then for (b), we need to find $f(x)$ for $x>6$ where $f(x) = 64000$ (when the population grew back to its original size before the spill). This is just a simple equation:

$$4x+8 = 64$$

Solving this gives $x=14$. This is $8$ years after the spill.